# UITextView doesn't support Paste !

Tags: iphone, uitextview, copy-paste

i created persian custom keyboard , my letters type on `UITextView` , but the `UITextView` dosn't support paste function ! why ?  i don't check the editable option .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `UITextViewDelegate`, you can try implementing `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:` to see what, if any, text is being pasted. I'm not sure if it's going to be called on the paste event though.

Answer (score 0):

If the text view isn't editable, the user can't paste to it.